# All browsers displaying italic text when not supposed to

Tags: google-chrome, text, safari, osx-lion, italics

I am having a problem with my browsers (Safari, Chrome, and FF) displaying text in italics when it's not supposed to be italicized. This is happening on multiple sites including Google sites (Google, YouTube) as well as sites I have built and others (godaddy email, ford.com, even stackoverflow). Surprisingly though, it is not happening with my time tracker site (freeagent.com).

I have no idea what's going on. I have not installed any new software recently nor any new fonts. I am running Mac OS X lion.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem... text bold and italic in all browsers, websites, twitter, even emails... what I did to fix it was make sure that Arial was turned on permanently in my Suitcase... it should have been anyway as a system font I guess but who cares because it fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where all the email titles were bold in my GoDaddy Email, on several browsers and only at one computer. It all happened after installing Suitcase Fusion and copying over a font library to that specific computer. I followed Lisa's suggestion and permanently turned on another version of Arial (TrueType, version 3.05) and it did the trick: all the email titles are back to normal (bold if unread, regular if read).

Answer (score 0):

Check your Safari Preference (Command-,), and navigate to Appearance tab, double check and make sure that the Standard font is non-italic font.  Mine is Times 16.  Hope this helps.

Comment: there is 1 problem with this answer: checking safari's prefrences would not affect chrome or firefox at all.

Comment: Good point.  I ran into similar issues with Windows before, and I found out that my font library was messed up.  After copying the fonts from another computer that does not have issue, the problem goes away.  I am not 100% sure if this applies to Mac as well.

Comment: well i suppose it cant hurt. i just need to figure out how to copy the font library.

Comment: For other reasons i had to wipe and reinstall the OS and everything - which ultimately fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome to solve this you have to do the following:

- paste address bar the following and hit enter: `chrome://flags#disable-direct-write`
- Under *Disable DirectWrite Windows* click "Enable" (this will disable DirectWrite in fact (background becomes white)
- A button labeled "Relaunch Now" at the bottom of your screen will apear. Click that button and will relaunch Chrome with the new settings, and the text should appear normal after this.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had this problem on my Windows 7 machine, while running Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m.  None of the other fixes mentioned here worked for me.

Turns out that an installed application had reregistered some basic fonts, which lead to Chrome not being able to find the fonts. In my case it was NewspaperDirect's PressReader (which I don't recall ever installing), that modified the registry so some basic fonts pointed to .ttf files stored in PressReaders program files folder.

### Fix

1. Run regedit.exe (with admin privileges)
2. Navigate to the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts".
3. Scroll through the list of fonts, and locate any that are similar to "C:\Program Files (x86)\NewpaperDirect\PressReader\publisher\Styles\Fonts[*font name*].ttf"
4. Right click the value name and choose **Modify...**.
5. Remove the directory path, so that all that remains is the file name "[*font name*].ttf".
6. Repeat 4 and 5 for all bad registry values.
7. Restart Chrome.

[image: NewspaperDirect registry font bug]
<sup>*Registry value before fix*</sup>

[image: Modifying registry value]
<sup>*Bad registry value*</sup>

[image: Modified registry value]
<sup>*Good registry value*</sup>

[image: Fixed registry value]
<sup>*Fixed registry value*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

if you have same problem with other browsers too, it may because of some errors in your fonts in windows. try to reinstall default windows font in your font folder (c:/windows/fonts). you can copy default font from another pc or download it from here :
http://www.withsteps.com/404/how-i-restored-my-windows-7-default-fonts.html